# Rogue tableview keyboard, unable to dismiss - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, keyboard

**Exact Problem Discovered:** I select a textfield and enter a value.  Then I select a new textfield in a tableview cell, HOWEVER!  when the first textfield that was selected "didEndEdit" it reloads the tableview (by design).  This causes the "Rogue Keyboard".  The textfield in a cell that was selected presents its keyboard, but then the tableview is reloaded destroying the reference to the keyboard resulting in a stuck keyboard.

Has anyone encountered this, and if so what were some solutions?  I do NEED to reload the entire table after a textfield does end editing (so that a user doesnt need to press a button every time they are done entering in a value.

Background info, may not be relevant since the new discoveries.

I have a `UIViewController` with a View containing a textfield above a  `tableView`. inside the tableview there are 2 possible cell types.
Type 1: Has 1 textfield
Type 2: Has 2 textfields.

I am having keyboard management problems if a user goes to (for example) indexPath.row 2 and selected the textfield, then from within editing indePath.row 2 textfield, selected indexPath.row 3 textfield.  The second texfield does not get selected and the keyboard remains present and is unresponsive to any key presses.

The same issue persist with both cell of type 1 and 2 as described above.

I have tried `self.view.endEditing(True)` as well as resigningfirst responder's of ALL of the textfields.  None of these get this "Rogue" keyboard to disappear.

I have isolated the problem to **reloading my tableview** after the textfield does end editing.  For some reason talbeView.reloadData() causes a rogue keyboard... The reason is beyond me... Still looking for a fix

Comment: does that mean it's managed by a different view? try messing with the placeholder text or something. clean your project.

Comment: To be more specific, I have a view controller with a tableview inside. i am NOT using a TableViewController.  Attempted with project clean, to no avail.

Comment: did you type in the viewdidload 'myTextField.delegate = self' and add , UITextField delegate to your UIViewController class declaration?

Comment: check if the cell..textfield line is running by doing a print statement before it...

Comment: I dont have textfield.delegate = self in VDL, because the textfield is created in CellForRowAtIndexPath, is there a way that I can set its delegate there?  I have confirmed that the cell.textfield line is running with a print statement in project.  I believe my issue may be with the textfield.delegate, any experience setting it when created via tableview?

Comment: nah, you're on your own, pal. I'd paste that textfield.delegate = self wherever you can without getting any errors. If worst comes to worst try running that textfield.delegate thing in some other place.

Comment: Dang, ok I just set the textfields delegate in the cutsomCell Class, but the keyboard is still there, this is so frustrating lol!

Comment: did you do the UITextFieldDelegate thing in the class declaration? my only other weak advice is this: https://media.giphy.com/media/12bVDtXPOzYwda/giphy.gif

Comment: Yes :/ class NewItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {, then i even mage an action from storyboard of textfield didEnd edit and applied sender.resignFirstResponder() to no avail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132865/discussion-between-bearacuda13-and-jerland2).

Comment: Problem isolated and solved in new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613420/how-to-reload-all-tableview-cells-while-editing-a-textfield-in-a-tableview-cell

Comment: You fixed it, eh?

Comment: Yup! After a long time of troubleshooting i found the function responsible, which eventually led me to the conflicting life cycle of events Edit: Thank you for trying to help me figure it out, that led me to recreating a test project where i was able to isolate the bug!