# How to reload all tableview cells, while editing a textfield in a tableview cell - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

For Clarity I have a `UIView Controller` with a top view containing a `textfield`.  I also have a `tableview` below that each row containing 1 `textfield`.

The problem:  When I `"didEndEditing"` ANY of the textfields this means the one in the top view AND the ones in the tableview I want to save this information to core data and reload the `tableview`.

This works perfectly, *EXCEPT! When I Select a textfield (anywhere) enter a value, then from being selected in one textfield, select another textfield.*  This causes a keyboard to become stuck that will never disappear.

I have diagnosed that this is because when `"DidEndEditing"` is called I lose reference to the textfield i just selected (whos keyboard is up) due to the cell being reloaded.

Has anyone encountered this before? Did anyone find an elegant solution to reloading the data to a `tableview cell` while selecting a `textfield` inside of it?

Edit: I have tried moving the `reloadData()` to the `"DidBeginEditing"` Function of the textfield, and successfully got the selection indicator to appear, but again the keyboard has no reference, even if i call become first responder after the `tableView.relaodData()`

Comment: Try to reload data when the keyboard is up instead of loading in on UItextField  Delegate.
Set observer for keyboard open and Close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would avoid reloading the table view at all so that you don't disturb the first responder status of your text.  You could either (1) insert and delete only what's changed or (2) redecorate cells that need updating.

## 1. Inserting and Deleting

So, instead of calling `myTableView.reloadData()`, figure out which index paths need to be added or removed and call the appropriate methods.

```
myTableView.insertRows(at: newIndexPaths, with: .automatic)
myTableView.deleteRows(at: oldIndexPaths, with: .automatic)
```

## 2. Redecorating

This requires a more modular approach to how you are dequeuing cells.  Instead of doing this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.data = dataArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Do this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
    decorate(cell, at: indexPath)
    return cell
}

func decorate(_ cell: UITableViewCell, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.data = dataArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

That way later on you can **redecorate**, i.e. update the content and configuration of the cells without reloading and disturbing the first responder status:

```
for cell in myTableView.visibleCells {
    if let indexPath = myTableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        decorate(cell: cell, at: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the placeholder text of all of the textfields rely on ALL other textfields, so relaodData() is CRUCIAL to functionality.  I could make it so all cells with empty textfields are reloaded, but that wouldnt help my problem as a user could select one of those and face the same bug.

Comment: It sounds more like your placeholder text relies on the data in your data model, not necessarily on the views themselves.  Views shouldn't be used as a source of truth, it should all stem from the models.  Could you refactor to construct this placeholder text differently?

Comment: Hmm... You are correct, currently whenever a textfield "didEndEditing" I save the data to my dataModel, then reload the tableview to update the placeholder text.  If there is another way to update EVERY cells placeholder text without tableView.relaodData() please share?

Comment: The redecorating method I explained in the answer sounds like what you need.  The configuration of the cell that triggers the update to the placeholder in the cell should be called from `decorate(_:at:)`, that way cells are configured when they are reloaded and can also be configured without being reloaded, i.e "redecorated".

Comment: Oh i see! I will give this a try, just a slight bit of confusion, should my usual cell setup (say adding a UIControl event DidEndEditing still go in CellForROw?) and only put the cell.textfield.placeholder = dataArray[indexpath.row] in redecorate?  I believe this is so, jsut want to make sure I am running with the correct idea

Comment: Sounds like either method will work, but the idea is that `cellForRow` is one-time setup that won't ever change, and `redecorate` is for configuration details that will change over the course of a cells lifetime before it is reloaded.

Comment: THIS IS BRILLIANT! Thank you, I love this concept as well, Am I correct in calling redecorate would be much less resource intensive than continually recalling tableView.relaodData()?

Comment: This solution fits my needs like a pair of gloves.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried storing the indexpath before reloading your tableview and using it to find your cell and set the textfield inside it as first responder after the reload ?

Comment: I have gottan a solution using this method before, but it is 80% correct, in that there is the case where I jsut open the view -> Enter Text into the topView textfield, then go to select a textfield in the tableview and this bug occurs.  Once a textfield is selected in the tableview, then the solution works perfectly.  But that first edge case is what still makes it buggy.

Comment: The problem with this is, my editingDidBegin does not get called when I select that textfield in a tableview cell

Comment: -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([indexPath row] == ((NSIndexPath*)[[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] lastObject]).row){
        //end of loading
        //for example [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    }
} add this in your code, and make sure that you set your textField there as first responder