# How to remove white spacing after hiding a cell in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview that opens up a section every time I tap on one of the fields,
to hide that section I tried attaching the cell in the class
and doing:

```
passwordCreationCell.isHidden = true
```

the problem with that that every time I do it, I get a white empty cell,

[image]

how do I remove the white spacing? 
or how do I remove the cell from display \ add it again?

Comment: You should remove the cell by changing the count in the number of rows and update your table.

Comment: Don't "hide" the cell, manage your datasource in order to not show it (your array source, the number of row in section, etc.)

Comment: Or you can change the height on that view, and use automatic row height

Comment: passwordCreationCell.alpha  = 0  wil remove the extra space too.

Comment: @Abu Ul Hassan no it doeswn't i tried it

Comment: @Juan Curti  can you give code example of that ?

Comment: @Larme  donig that would force me to call tableViewMain.reloadData() which would close my keyboard everytime i call it, and i cannot do it

Comment: passwordCreationCell.alpha = 0
passwordCreationCell.isHidden = true
can you try this one ?

Comment: @ Abu Ul Hassan i tried again, still didn't remove the white space

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409370/uitableview-reloaddata-automatically-calls-resignfirstresponder ? or https://stackoverflow.com/a/41614125/1801544 ?

Answer (score 2):

This case can be solved by two different ways

Either Remove hidden cells `indexpaths` from `tableview` or if you want the cell to be there on the `tableview` return 0 in `heightForRowAtIndexpath`